# How to pass props into jest test in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm new to React and testing. I'm trying to test a component that has a conditional render:

```
render() {
if (this.props.fetched === true){
  return (
    <div className="search">
      <div className="">
        <SearchBar getCountry={this.getCountry} /> <br/>
        <Results country={this.props.country}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
} else { return (
    <div className="search">
      <div className="">
        <SearchBar getCountry={this.getCountry} /> <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
)}
```

}
}

In my test, I'm trying to pass the this.props.fetched into the wrapper to test that  shows up after fetched=true. Right now this is my test:

```
it('renders results after search', () => {
  const fetched = true;
  const wrapper = shallow(<Search store={store} {...fetched}/>);
  expect(wrapper.find('Results').length).toEqual(1);
});
```

But my test keeps failing, so I must not be passing props in. What is the proper way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
it('renders results after search', () => {
  const fetched = true;
  const wrapper = shallow(<Search store={store} fetched={fetched} />);
  expect(wrapper.find('Results').length).toEqual(1);
});
```

then you can do the same thing either omitting fetched or setting to false

Comment: that doesn't work for me either, and I do have a test for the initial state without the prop, which works

Comment: that's the proper way to pass props. The issue is most likely finding `Results` - remember you're shallow rendering so that component won't fully render.

Comment: @peter176 in the test, you can do a `console.log(wrapper.prop('fetched'))` to make sure fetched prop is correct

Comment: true - you can also do `const res = wrapper.find('Results')` and log it out.  Try `Results` without the quotes.  It's not a string, it's a component - also make sure you're importing it into the test

Comment: @bsapaka the prop is false, which explains it. how do I properly pass it in?

Comment: @jsw324 weirdly when I run the test without passing in the prop    expect(wrapper.find('SearchBar').length).toEqual(1); passes, but when I pass in the prop it doesn't pass

Comment: If you don't include the prop it's considered `false`

Comment: if you like the answer please accept it as correct :)

Comment: no, but SearchBar should be contained in both cases

Comment: @peter176 by chance, did you do something like `import Results from '../SearchResults'`, where the imported name does not match the actual declared component name?

Comment: @peter176 sorry i was MIA yesterday -- any luck?

Comment: @jsw324 with mount i'm able to console log fetched = true, but it's still not finding a results

Answer (score 1):

```
it('renders results after search', () => {
  const fetched = true;
  const wrapper = mount(<Search store={store} {...fetched}/>);
  expect(wrapper.find('Results').length).toEqual(1);
});
```

Use `mount` instead of `shallow` that should fix your problem. or you can alternatively try with `wrapper.update()` keeping the `shallow` (I'm not sure about this).

FYR: [Diff between Shallow and Mount](https://gist.github.com/fokusferit/e4558d384e4e9cab95d04e5f35d4f913)

Comment: mount gets my console log to show true for fetched, but doesn't make the conditional render statement show my Results component